# Discrepancy between Top Answerers on tag info and tag topusers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, top-answers

Once I saw that order of Top Answers on 
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/[tag]/info
and All time Answerers on
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/[tag]/topusers were different

I believe it happened, when several top answerers had the same number of total score, but different number of answers.

Comment: Would help if you mentioned which tag so we could look at it... I'm not seeing any issues just browsing a few random ones...

Comment: It happened on this tag - http://stackoverflow.com/tags/iphone-privateapi/info, but it's not there anymore (because total score is different).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of statistics on tag pages are periodically calculated and cached, they will sometimes disagree just because the caches are a little out of sync with each other.